# ¿Cómo puedo listar todos los cronjobs en mi servidor?

Tags: linux, unix, crontab, cron

Estoy administrando un servidor y con frecuencia me doy cuenta de que ocurren cosas automática y/o periódicamente. ¿Cómo puedo saber cuál es su origen?

Después de mirar logs, procesos, directorios de los usuarios... acabo dándome cuenta de que se trata de un proceso lanzado mediante `cronjobs`.
Pero claro, revisar los cronjobs de cada uno de los usuarios es tedioso y hacer `crontab -l -u <usuario>` para cada uno de ellos puede llevar mucho rato.

Por tanto, ¿existe alguna manera más fácil de ver qué contenido tiene el crontab de cada uno de los usuarios de un servidor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Sí! Tal y como comentas en la pregunta, `crontab -l` sirve para mostrar el contenido de `crontab` para el usuario con el que estás trabajando. Esto es así para la mayoría de las distribuciones de cron ([más info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7060/40596)).

Después, `crontab -l -u <usuario>` te permite saber cuál es el contenido de `crontab` para el usuario `<usuario>`.

Por tanto, para conocer el contenido de todos los `crontab`s la cuestión radica en circular por todos los nombres de usuario del sistema y lanzar el comando `crontab -l -u <usuario>` para cada uno de ellos.

Dado que `/etc/passwd` contiene tal listado, usémoslo. Tal y como vemos aquí gráficamente, sus campos están separados por dos puntos y lo que nosotros deseamos es el primer campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, debemos extraer el primer elemento de cada línea de este fichero.

Total, que este script hace lo que queremos:

```
while IFS=":" read -r usuario _
do
   echo "crontab del usuario ${usuario}:"
   crontab -l -u "$usuario"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Este usa la técnica más ampliamente recomendada de leer un archivo (descrita en 
[How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).

Básicamente:

- `while; do ... done < fichero` circula a través del fichero `fichero`.
- `IFS=":"` define el separador de campos como `:`
- `read -r usuario _` lee el primer campo en `$usuario` y el resto en la variable "tonta" `_`, pues no necesitamos su contenido.
- `crontab -l -u "$usuario"` busca el contenido del crontab del usuario `$usuario`.

Nótese que este script debe ejecutarse con el usuario `root`, pues este es el que puede ver el `crontab` de todos los usuarios por tema de permisos.

Answer (score -2):

Podes hacerlo de varias maneras:

Ejecutar esta sentencia por root:

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Ejecutar esta otra sentencia por root:

```
cat /etc/passwd | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):.*$/crontab -u \1 -l 2>\&1/' | grep -v "no crontab for" | sh
```

Las que cité anteriormente podés realizar un script.

O si no realiza este script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd)
do echo $user && crontab -u $user -l
echo " "
done
```

Una de las tres anteriores te va a servir. Ya depende de tu elección.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users/2759975) utilizado

Comment: `cat archivo | sed | grep` no va a servir: primero, `cat fichero | sed` es innecesario, pues puedes decir directamente `sed fichero`; después, el `grep` solo afecta a stdout, mientras que "no crontab for" es stderr. Además, lo que estás haciendo es imprimir la cadena "crontab -u ...", cuando lo que queremos es ejecutarla.

Comment: En cuanto a `for user in $(...)` no está nada recomenada: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Básicamente, puede perderse el formato y expandir incorrectamente con `glob`.

Comment: En cuanto al script completo, `echo " "` no es necesario. Con `echo` a secas ya tienes una línea en blanco. Además´, decir `echo $user && crontab -u $user -l` indica que quieres ejecutar el segundo comando si el primero no falla. Un `echo` nunca fallará, por lo que complica la readabilidad del código.

Comment: En resumidas cuentas: ¡muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Sin embargo, conviene revisar cada una de las sugerencias pues incluyen formulaciones no recomendadas para la tarea de leer un archivo.

Comment: No entiendo porque alguien voto como  negativo, si resuelve la pregunta. Puede ser que no sea la respuesta esperada porque no cumple buenas prácticas pero tampoco se especificó en la pregunta

Comment: Lo que a mí me sorprende es que la respuesta siga igual después de todos los comentarios que dejé sobre los errores que contiene.

Comment: Pero en este caso que hago? Porque resuelve. Puede ser que no sea lo esperado pero no esta mal. Cambio totalmente la respuesta? Y los comentarios que quedaron los van a tener sentido

Comment: La gracia en este sitio estriba en aportar respuestas útiles que puedan servir en el futuro: añadir algo que funciona pero que contiene errores no sirve de demasiado, pues crea confusión y perpetúa malas prácticas. Si yo dejé los comentarios fue para que puedas [edit] la respuesta y corregir lo que falla. Los comentarios se borran sin ningún problema una vez quedan obsoletos, no hay que temer por eso.

Comment: Perfecto. Pero entonces si se toma ese criterio de esa manera mas de la mitad de las respuestas deberian de tener votos negativos. Yo no considero  que este mal oara in voto negativo

Comment: Para eso esta en comentario. Como dije anteriormente. Puede ser que no cumpla con la respuesta esperada pero no esta mal. Rsuelve. Ademas si buscas en stavkoverflow es inglés la misma pregunta existen miles de respuestas iguales o similares. A ninguna se le voto encontra por aportar si resuelve ela pregunta. Solo tiene votoa negativos si esta totalmente mal. Creo que debemoa de seguir la misma linea

Comment: Uy pues peor me lo pones: me doy cuenta que estás copiando respuestas de [so] sin citarlas explícitamente. [Una](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31873590/1983854), [dos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3185772/1983854) y [tres](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759975/1983854). Es importante leer [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](/help/referencing). Pero, sobre todo, creo que es importante como programadores poner empeño en aprender y mejorar. Mis comentarios dieron buenas pautas y creo que pueden ser útiles para dejar una respuesta maja.

Comment: Mi respues no tiene errores. Dunciona  resuelve. Puede ser que no sea de buenas prácticas. Pero creo que si se esperaba eso. Se deberia de haber puesto en la pregunta. Es cierto q7e se quiera dar respuestas de calidad pero con un voto negatvo parece que esta mal.  Y nonlo esta

Comment: Ok. Voy a tener en cuanta para las próximas respuestas. Gracias

Comment: Ya agregue en la respuesta en el link. Muchas gracias por todo. Me re sirvió y voy a considerar todo lo que me dijiste para las próximas respuestas. Muy agradecido