# [~:]$ Aparece en el terminal de macos

Tags: macos, terminal

Al abrir la consola de mac OS aparece lo siguiente

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
[~:]$
```

Y no me deja hacer nada, no se como solucionarlo y he buscado en internet pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: puedes revisar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713312/bash-rbenv-command-not-found-comes-up-every-time-i-open-a-terminal-window

Comment: Parece que tienes una instalación de `ruby` incompleta. Prueba a ejecutar [los comandos indicados aquí](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/976), para desinstalar-reinstalar `ruby` de nuevo.

Comment: También, puede deberse a algún cronjob que se está lanzando a cada instante. Para ver todos los cron que hay activados, puedes ejecutar esto: `for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done` y verificar si tu usuario no tiene algún cronjob que esté ejecutando ese comando.

Comment: Funciono!! Mil gracias A.Cedano :)

Comment: ¿Cuál fue la solución, para ponerla como respuesta y pueda servir a otros? ¿Fue completar la instalación ejecutando los diferentes comandos o era que tenías un cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

Este error se ha reportado varias veces en Github y en otros sitios. En todos ellos estaba relacionado a una posible instalación de [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)  inacabada.

Podrías resolverlo abriendo una nueva ventana de `Terminal` y copiando/pegando esta secuencia de comandos<sup>1</sup>:

```bash
cd ~
rm -rf .rbenv/
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Si de este modo no se resuelve, puede que haya un cron job activado que esté observando ese comportamiento.

Puedes verificar los cronjobs que hay en el sistema mediante esta secuencia de comandos<sup>2</sup>:

```
while IFS=":" read -r usuario _
do
   echo "crontab del usuario ${usuario}:"
   crontab -l -u "$usuario"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Si ves alguno *sospechoso* prueba a desactivarlo.

---

#### Notas:

- <sup>1</sup> Posteado como respuesta a este problema [en Github](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/976).
- <sup>2</sup> Ver **[la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42962/29967)** a la pregunta [¿Cómo puedo listar todos los cronjobs en mi servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42961/29967)

Comment: Es algo más _limpio_ y seguro decir `while IFS=":" read -r usuario _
do;
   echo "crontab del usuario ${usuario}:";
   crontab -l -u "$usuario";
done < /etc/passwd`. Véase [¿Cómo puedo listar todos los cronjobs en mi servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42962/83)

Comment: @fedorqui no me funciona así. Se queda solamente esto en pantalla:  `>`

Comment: Disculpa, copié el código multilínea en una sola línea y olvidé poner punto y coma tras cada uno de ellos. Corregido

Comment: @fedorqui Ahora da: `syntax error near unexpected token `done'`

Comment: Caramba, esto de escribir sin una consola a mano es malo. Perdón por hacer perder el tiempo. Recomiendo coger el código multilínea de la respuesta que enlazo. Lo correcto era poner `usuario _; do ...` para que quede en total así: `while IFS=":" read -r usuario _; do    echo "crontab del usuario ${usuario}:";    crontab -l -u $usuario"; done < /etc/passwd`

Comment: En efecto @fedorqui mucho más claro así. He editado e indicado el enlace. Muchas gracias.